# How does a direct url to an image hosted on Tumblr load a page with the image embedded instead?

Tags: http, web, url, tumblr

Lately, a direct url for an image (i.e., `https://64.media.tumblr.com/....jpg`) hosted on tumblr will load a page with the image embedded in it, rather than linking directly to the image. I'm wondering if anybody can help shed some light on how this works? Maybe it's a redirect? I'd like to see if there's a way to stop this from happening client-side.

Comment: It must be some server side function tumblr have implemented. i.e. for jpg/gif/png render the image with a html wrapper. I think the only way around this would be to write something which fetches the image via the API.

Comment: Did you gain any clarity on this? I'm trying to write a script that involves getting tumblr hosted images, but I'm getting web pages back. When I go to the links in a browser, sometimes it loads the image, but on refresh it'll load the webpage with embedded image. I thought it was redirects too, but it doesn't look like it.

Comment: Interesting find: I consistently get the image using Postman and axios, but get the webpage with chrome and puppeteer, so I guess it's somehow a browser thing? User agents maybe.